# Alex monad wrapper difference between ; and skip

Tags: haskell, alex

Using the monadwrapper in alex, it seems you can skip using either `;` or the `{skip}` action. They generate different code, but I can't seem to find the difference. Why is this obvious question not addressed in the documentation?